# Node Streams - how to read a file stream's data

Tags: node.js, stream

**I'm trying to compress an image, convert it to dataURI, and save it to a text file.**

I'm using GraphicsMagic to read and compress an image.

I want to "pipe" the data from the image into a stream, and convert this image data to dataURI, so that I can avoid creating an intermediary image.

```
var file = '/path/to/file.png'

gm(file).compress('JPEG').quality(20).stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
   stdout.pipe(streamChunkReader);
});
```

Now, within streamChunkReader, I would convert the image data to dataURI, e.g:

```
content = dataURI.format('.png', dataChunk);
console.log(content); //"data:image/png;base64,eGtjZA=="
```

Although, I'm not sure what `streamChunkReader` would look like to be able to get the image data

After looking at what methods are called on streamChunkReader, I imagine its something like:

```
var streamChunkReader = {

    write: function (imageData) {
        console.log(imageData); // the image data

        // so I could do
        console.log(dataURI.format('.png', imageData);) //"data:image/png;base64,eGtjZA=="
    }

}
```

But when I log `imageData`, it is `<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff fe 00 0f 4...` and I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here.  To answer your question as to what `<Buffer ff d8 ff...` is, that is a Buffer object which contains binary data.  When you dump these to your console, you see the hexadecimal representation of it.

You didn't tell us what you are using for `dataURI`, but by looking at your example, at least the `.format` function doesn't appear to support streams.  If you want to use it, you will need to get a Buffer containing your entire file.  You can use [`fs.readFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) for that.

If it were me, I would use a Base64-encoding TransformStream.  I haven't used this one, but check it out:  https://www.npmjs.org/package/base64-stream  Also, check out the [Sharp NPM package](https://github.com/lovell/sharp).  It uses libvips in the background, and can be much faster than GraphicsMagick.  The installation process isn't the easiest (at least on CentOS), but it's well worth it.